# Using matlab fit object as a function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Matlab fit is no doubt useful but it is not clear how to use it as a function
apart from trivial integration and differentiation given on the official website:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/example-differentiating-and-integrating-a-fit.html

For example given a fit stored in the object 'curve' one can evaluate
curve(x) to get a number. But how one would, e.g. integrate |curve(x)|^2 (apart from clumsily creating a new fit)? Trying naively

```
 curve = fit(x_vals,y_vals,'smoothingspline');
 integral(curve(x)*curve(x), 0, 1)
```

gives an error:

```
 Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true.
```

I have also tried a work around by definining a normal function and an implicit function for the integrand (below) but both give the same error.

```
 func=@(x)(curve(x))...; % trial solution 1
 function func_val=func(curve, x)...; % trial solution 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining function for the integrand followed by integration with option 'ArrayValued' set to 'true' works:

```
 func=@(x)(curve(x)*curve(x));
 integral(func,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the function vectorized, i.e use element-wise operations like `curve(x).*curve(x)` or `curve(x).^2`.

Also make sure that the shape of the output matches the input, i.e a row input gives a row output, similarly a column comes out as a column. It seems that evaluating the fit object always returns a column vector (e.g. `f(1:10)` returns a 10x1 vector not 1x10).

With that said, here is an example:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi,100)';
y = sin(x);
y = y + 0.5*y.*randn(size(y));
f = fit(x, y, 'smoothingspline');
```

now you can integrate as:

```
integral(@(x) reshape(f(x).^2,size(x)), 0, 1)
```

in this case, it can be simplified as a simple transpose:

```
integral(@(x) (f(x).^2)', 0, 1)
```